# Sending email with PHPMailer from Gmail SMTP to Hotmail

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, hotmail

I'm stuck in the following problem and cannot find a solution in Google.

I want to send an email to a user from my PHP app. I created a gmail account, set up PHPMailer, and wrote code to connect it to Gmail's SMTP.

Everything works fine but all emails to Hotmail go to a spam folder.
I tried to send email from the Gmail interface for that account, and it goes into the Inbox folder as expected.

I've investigated Message Sources for both emails and though they differ in some places I couldn't find the reason why the one sent from the Gmail interface went to the inbox, and the one sent from my PHP app went  into spam.

Both emails have passed the SPF and DKIM check.

CMM-Authentication-Results header for message in spam:

> CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is
>    209.85.215.41; identity alignment result is pass and alignment mode is  relaxed) smtp.mailfrom=avel80274@gmail.com; dkim=pass (identity
>   alignment  result is pass and alignment mode is relaxed)
>   header.d=gmail.com; x-hmca=pass  header.id=avel80274@gmail.com

CMM-Authentication-Results header for message in inbox:

> CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is
>   74.125.82.44;  identity alignment result is pass and alignment mode is relaxed)  smtp.mailfrom=avel80274@gmail.com; dkim=pass (identity
>   alignment result is  pass and alignment mode is relaxed)
>   header.d=gmail.com; x-hmca=pass  header.id=avel80274@gmail.com

My PHP code:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');

require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "avel80274@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "<my pass>";


$mail->setFrom('avel80274@gmail.com', "Alex Vel");
$mail->addReplyTo('avel80274@gmail.com', "Alex Vel");
$mail->addAddress('alex.velickiy@hotmail.com');


$mail->Subject = 'Test subj';
$mail->msgHTML("Test body");

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Spam message source:

```
Received: from DB6PR0601MB2584.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.168.81.141) by
 VI1PR0601MB2591.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.173.70.12) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id
 15.1.619.10 via Mailbox Transport; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 10:37:47 +0000
Received: from AM3PR06CA043.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.141.192.161) by
 DB6PR0601MB2584.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.168.81.141) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id
 15.1.609.9; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 10:37:47 +0000
Received: from VE1EUR01FT005.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:f400:7e01::208) by AM3PR06CA043.outlook.office365.com
 (2a01:111:e400:882b::33) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_0,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id 15.1.609.9 via Frontend
 Transport; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 10:37:47 +0000
Received: from BAY004-MC4F47.hotmail.com (10.152.2.51) by
 VE1EUR01FT005.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.2.142) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.1.619.6 via Frontend Transport; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 10:37:46 +0000
Received: from mail-lf0-f46.google.com ([209.85.215.46]) by BAY004-MC4F47.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Sun, 11 Sep 2016 03:37:39 -0700
Received: by mail-lf0-f46.google.com with SMTP id u14so70392317lfd.1
        for <alex.velickiy@hotmail.com>; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 03:37:39 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=date:to:from:reply-to:subject:message-id:mime-version
         :content-transfer-encoding;
        bh=I5VrdY4Y9bKfPKaJq4B9NA4WdFYKMWKjuDI0LqsfPyY=;
        b=G+f2yNPuDdMHolg6en2XkBZKg7F4GiWSc27lvAady4QNNonqIqZEmq9Wvm9WWyi9xK
         DH9jwvs55mQrIZSpW9JNAcUV3kGKRfqLMYJuwrld9Fh5jtlsd5WoVf/bG828I9P1iyy4
         ENiZvtCAAWxXrHRSw9hBWdJ0/udSeAMJS9vp9rM7OJy+qaDRhrJB9kbnmMnB0rT++KEL
         d+GFvIlP5FgX0FT1UrrT0wubmrmbfrXFFdb8T0tkwb85wrK/8yOmVcXKe/G/KRsn3IrK
         ihEsYOcx51jJSv8jveKgeXOawI/fUvOvc5quRa3DlrttQWPsTA0yk6CSkqUb9GaSjjB7
         KRRQ==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:date:to:from:reply-to:subject:message-id
         :mime-version:content-transfer-encoding;
        bh=I5VrdY4Y9bKfPKaJq4B9NA4WdFYKMWKjuDI0LqsfPyY=;
        b=NxAbEcmZCtcXzUaXisLP7roXx2nPVJowd/EZVmIiXlVhcu3lEGABdnsOJd5svhRQBd
         YYvRdtWlRVV5z+gCe0OQlDvQcqlTbqcBMJfZrjIaeCVkTUdkum4PU30YolZ1FMFoJFBW
         kHqHgiIL88lONgvsg0kn9pIP3Av0X+W5jQ6u9SnLhX/8yBN3I5o8nvMBXrHB4dcTrs0s
         L7i7l0OAzelaRE05M4iRCgOvlPPsJV1y8WN68hVKhpGGiyV12NrMbpgpE2OzzisNMi9S
         nQoEWLQNQDL9Pq8aab6v49C86hYgWWCgbd3/DrsXthvKuxrARd+N4BfGY+6qMmmTahWz
         hU0w==
X-Gm-Message-State: AE9vXwO1RX9ALuWT4eryhgBg1WVY85WPvpymojfes0Ze1JjSa2gX2eb0EQ9HbjtAqmaWwA==
X-Received: by 10.25.33.72 with SMTP id h69mr3070393lfh.8.1473590258897;
        Sun, 11 Sep 2016 03:37:38 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: avel80274@gmail.com
Received: from 127.0.0.1 ([92.60.179.209])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id g70sm2227149ljg.22.2016.09.11.03.37.37
        for <alex.velickiy@hotmail.com>
        (version=TLS1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
        Sun, 11 Sep 2016 03:37:37 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Sun, 11 Sep 2016 13:37:35 +0300
To: alex.velickiy@hotmail.com
From: Alex Vel <avel80274@gmail.com>
Reply-To: Alex Vel <avel80274@gmail.com>
Subject: Test subj
Message-ID: <158c240a0e56c955eb9db88446716a3c@127.0.0.1>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.16 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_158c240a0e56c955eb9db88446716a3c"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 11 Sep 2016 10:37:39.0782 (UTC) FILETIME=[85082E60:01D20C18]
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: 96123d74-b931-4e8f-3160-08d3da2fabfc
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
CMM-sender-ip: 209.85.215.46
CMM-sending-ip: 209.85.215.46
CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is
 209.85.215.46; identity alignment result is pass and alignment mode is
 relaxed) smtp.mailfrom=avel80274@gmail.com; dkim=pass (identity alignment
 result is pass and alignment mode is relaxed) header.d=gmail.com; x-hmca=pass
 header.id=avel80274@gmail.com
CMM-X-SID-PRA: avel80274@gmail.com
CMM-X-AUTH-Result: PASS
CMM-X-SID-Result: PASS
CMM-X-Message-Status: n:n
CMM-X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD00
CMM-X-Message-Info: o9rlR4nWDTeVaZOwk/5NeLGGHBjl9pZxlMJ7WFmL+zPG/j0RtcGlzz+YFabnTrPu3WSuYy4+UMzPFvzGxPeeh1cIOpfitxdtAV03A4bAYi8UqHKtxZmdiGjEDJFN/KTCK6+dIJJWmDVhSXlvxzsMzKlGzovJdeC/nsqON8ArEEJs4vDl92yTb6/DVYZCZfdwc9+qd+lgof4m99EBGaORmEmKMB5mMCIWSHB/3vevKN//KDwjPKmeNQ==
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 5
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR01FT005;1:E6RicrZS0j3gjmSVWdBOmlapqKwShHCsmBWJvcbN565P3enP7LYkMKUcIF//FWStP878lEdbF2k88Z9+uw8VHIcYFyF9qfolmGQcG37dABzAZSsJKFG+ClffAkoboLUjEE789j+mtiD8yQZhH0EDdA==
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;SFV:SPM;SFS:(28900001);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:5;SRVR:DB6PR0601MB2584;H:BAY004-MC4F47.hotmail.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:en;
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 96123d74-b931-4e8f-3160-08d3da2fabfc
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;DB6PR0601MB2584;2:wyUGnM2AVbQ3rBQ334oTDkLGz0ih7bZxsfsedUh0X8kFDWGZSiZtcY4RWB3JW0B+c0NJ0aAga5JC0Q9a23uWQSTC6/tYBRZWIFxkfP7vcdCMYe9IZap12f4+UbCL9w3EW+A1EPqtAlyDGds2YcSSQYraBt9fJK+mxhku5HRsV5+EHdXIYMUr/3wEz/T0viYe757Q8DxW9AFekO4hOqdtiQ==;3:4TyuKMgOG3oBPzoCDsB4pepGd8aPuqRgZWjTXgPBERMf+fScEid41S1qG57m4gM+gfsQdXo+rkoQg63pMv0t3chmR1lDwyQua4rdL/6bByLeMnDNJsNbRkbWjcgkkv5t/stHi3ysK4Hdr9neBWF6yP59b9dsGZNHXATzQ9BB3pk=;25:g28qeVmAkz+qk5r+bZfv+jHSim5HJ/QDKtRr9vD79RKqUXi0UGpLhxfIOV0xrCWtB0dw5GEruw7jmDJJFgKAZatFoTgXkNVmSUFGwK9r+UGw7EN2PPD23LAOYzCJw2yZ8u09txj3SV7F/kbJGep7dlA8UPGuf1rbSPyCV38rOznW96AM7p62mwAhjqaFD/WI8iTMUEcru+HKBIQYF85LUpWlSPxZ0H30w360ch3mSB/Xsfoor7b+DXS1vI1RF3vCSY6LaEwpW5I4KEor0e1ay46HbN4QBhQrNGGtjuxqPQJOl1ZTefv2ZZE+Vsj5Z3cucJ3+Adkzyr0i4Ptu00dcoQ==;31:FKYVjH3lj2Ja6IZUenYhL907QZsYEBghy8nGNhujqXJFsqZkpRVyJQWI2z+suAZOXYLK0xTz1sI6nNPwYFfmeX4lIwrf0RmCs4hWEwc1rNpFlADEyQ0CcPOacCw0G2wu
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(8291501002);SRVR:DB6PR0601MB2584;
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(82015046);SRVR:DB6PR0601MB2584;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:DB6PR0601MB2584;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;DB6PR0601MB2584;4:QddeecgwRkuRYvtTB/9d8HHWRGrpRalWbEAvvvFrfOmu3ZtlxhY1cSXxmtbeNFKAJe+9ciKkCED5YMHoxMy0d4NeSLgjQSeEXDSIY3NcF0I6Gaib1C9ULhEHUp7npBeyEquyxkY+o5vAf6nyyHE4o5aFbRX7KBAwyh/raD9EI6o=;23:A94D5SJtmZzf3ce9dc/RqMZa3eiuy2MY8XEEZAZqkGWkElLLpoB5p5o6zsRPbTvwRhn9nT9tkhU/qg2aok/0GDCows1OLZ9+EqgDc6dVIPoEl1qQlAHWHtGEep8BcZGxsfjVqKAID2P1MxPacGluFvsLLX+l8cN3cqyccFbsD7e+5TgDNSfE/weJZN0yUJOTD+aekGRRpc+RnE9y7tWTxGdyviKaRGCR2TgO/oLm/8A=;6:QeshgB+KLZwNDGuT7obDsCbl2XekPR03v6KMo0A6SoeQNA24VHOKAT+6wtbsvLH2XNmANl79eifoYyHsysD4JuQ9+e7fG43Mwtn6rDEYffC1bKqi8YfjhDBO0lLHaJ8HdSmiD+6UC3EtSlZsQtuKZGHl5kF9j0h+AtmivOCaaPknJ25V04Py5x4brZuO5IeeXtlqzIBDN5e27Al/cZh+QQ==;5:C92E2ELd/rbNKaNewWrhotMhrEdHBrDA7BPk/f+KGWXMz3GzIZi+uoxw0EbCcMFzHv9bXNmqMqzlxAC7f7pUOvG8wdEHh/FsosdZDU0NcZWvqLMu8nEsoMt8uRadmMRw3lh1vIUuIdzZqgWioWHpgg==;24:J9DhhD4ZxZ25hZkvpNKUFv4rQz7g+h72/MZlQd8yfBq3Cs6XpFlPFb8Dw11XWr+E1I/Rs2/yxvJsnBHbg7DaPw==
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:22
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;DB6PR0601MB2584;7:VyKcPxgLxY3Zne+1pRsmq6GgycDasa3w1C7rccDaH3aSjYuLjLZXy2d0fSS2GaNPrlLawTHgxQ2Etpz/FM2Y/lqKszuxxRrDKTHkVxnYHBjh/5EjLSnUNH8cWNYPemEkOBlxyWy/a2Vobq+/ISSZztyvl7unIzuf28RJNwcnk1VgO4QheFHlzsZ/puUhD2Wo3fVlDklXJXnjiJbzcGQpeUHPOLfFEaAiQ7a6HMfco8c4itN856OfCTOYzr2d02J6pbgdAqvuubfuijhJxjOQoQ==
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 11 Sep 2016 10:37:46.1090
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: DB6PR0601MB2584
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: VE1EUR01FT005.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.9644362
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    =?us-ascii?Q?1;VI1PR0601MB2591;9:LBmssjI/LVnO+W7DtnneCbTREAAxx722GOZjO5R5?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?F/ZXtNg9TJzug99kf5mUdprqOQwr+oIorkghiw6tuQ4NYV2ghKXACxNwPkRl?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?hs2zl0MBNyQ7tDTzK1kbNH9ZTqC/i1ScEPuyJZcsDKbi2iDg1qGbleQKXnF7?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?5Nxil2MNZKz/Ck9IpXDY8nmyuaR68GWKU70bEjR4b2KRbw9neLA/+qfJ/oAg?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?qDLtYJYWNKYb13kVF75SY/FBmInt4R0kn72ZhBQt+YX9sPT9Z8Jbbyx19ATA?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?jmFDRmUz7TVcuyK2YtO9ckIz33vjefhyaw2DV0FGIVKVXxC0BKKt58LNkVtr?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?DHo7z3hkNCipskELnz1evOyF9lEWxUYYL5NryXM7Z6HM9mZbk8VXIURNyorV?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Z4XaNW0gfDqMHBuvLGZKJh+op3J04haM3/Ix4yPDBngG1ZFkM/KWrd4dQHaM?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?zu4A+AXHyiAiQxUqAOwe/sc8UXZ/raa0Sxd2snXrK7wKcVPtA2VH7vIvTA+b?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?rkVbFNb6JuUCkQtZSXnRYtmpI+dppAip9a3wTjWBzVTL7y0d668lp4OrwRH3?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?A/0B0Z/s0Py8K1/t/Ee00WGTyDsxoY2VU/cTgoloSknkPhNc85Cv2aL47PhA?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?meC9qT/KKN8YmHxotah+tbrakQ6+5+HnqyKBQevAlIBZZqlfZH42WQZW7Ol8?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?5bo0Mw8VxE56UiT9C+Yts8LxtYqC7jSGvXzcgerbkLu25fWvzaiwdu8Vc0Y9?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?nkoTol406Sy6GVqhcuYOuqtXPFSZ/9Vhh8BBK7+1Cxm4F6XfKfV5amMDrZlV?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?u8xFYyfaViTRO/FtmpZBGseWHzEyxu3+NznfX5Mc4FKx99Pn/vCeNUTMOOmJ?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?RjwKNXUQfVs2gysH0V13oDRl92vCa2yGm85REqSFN3jURbV4CvyV+QSy3h6N?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?JT/aedZAt56NawuDOajTsrlhRXRKMCsKH/3/k2yImj/SfN2WYCQky60NvVgM?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Y++hWo7NeyVfK1g1Kdi859Mp?=
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SenderIP:209.85.215.46;WIMS-SPF:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-DKIM:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-822:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050)(102420017);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;
MIME-Version: 1.0

--b1_158c240a0e56c955eb9db88446716a3c
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    =?us-ascii?Q?1;VI1PR0601MB2591;9:LBmssjI/LVnO+W7DtnneCbTREAAxx722GOZjO5R5?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?F/ZXtNg9TJzug99kf5mUdprqOQwr+oIorkghiw6tuQ4NYV2ghKXACxNwPkRl?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?hs2zl0MBNyQ7tDTzK1kbNH9ZTqC/i1ScEPuyJZcsDKbi2iDg1qGbleQKXnF7?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?5Nxil2MNZKz/Ck9IpXDY8nmyuaR68GWKU70bEjR4b2KRbw9neLA/+qfJ/oAg?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?qDLtYJYWNKYb13kVF75SY/FBmInt4R0kn72ZhBQt+YX9sPT9Z8Jbbyx19ATA?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?jmFDRmUz7TVcuyK2YtO9ckIz33vjefhyaw2DV0FGIVKVXxC0BKKt58LNkVtr?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?DHo7z3hkNCipskELnz1evOyF9lEWxUYYL5NryXM7Z6HM9mZbk8VXIURNyorV?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Z4XaNW0gfDqMHBuvLGZKJh+op3J04haM3/Ix4yPDBngG1ZFkM/KWrd4dQHaM?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?zu4A+AXHyiAiQxUqAOwe/sc8UXZ/raa0Sxd2snXrK7wKcVPtA2VH7vIvTA+b?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?rkVbFNb6JuUCkQtZSXnRYtmpI+dppAip9a3wTjWBzVTL7y0d668lp4OrwRH3?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?A/0B0Z/s0Py8K1/t/Ee00WGTyDsxoY2VU/cTgoloSknkPhNc85Cv2aL47PhA?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?meC9qT/KKN8YmHxotah+tbrakQ6+5+HnqyKBQevAlIBZZqlfZH42WQZW7Ol8?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?5bo0Mw8VxE56UiT9C+Yts8LxtYqC7jSGvXzcgerbkLu25fWvzaiwdu8Vc0Y9?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?nkoTol406Sy6GVqhcuYOuqtXPFSZ/9Vhh8BBK7+1Cxm4F6XfKfV5amMDrZlV?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?u8xFYyfaViTRO/FtmpZBGseWHzEyxu3+NznfX5Mc4FKx99Pn/vCeNUTMOOmJ?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?RjwKNXUQfVs2gysH0V13oDRl92vCa2yGm85REqSFN3jURbV4CvyV+QSy3h6N?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?JT/aedZAt56NawuDOajTsrlhRXRKMCsKH/3/k2yImj/SfN2WYCQky60NvVgM?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Y++hWo7NeyVfK1g1Kdi859Mp?=
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SenderIP:209.85.215.46;WIMS-SPF:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-DKIM:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-822:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050)(102420017);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;

Test body


--b1_158c240a0e56c955eb9db88446716a3c
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    =?us-ascii?Q?1;VI1PR0601MB2591;9:LBmssjI/LVnO+W7DtnneCbTREAAxx722GOZjO5R5?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?F/ZXtNg9TJzug99kf5mUdprqOQwr+oIorkghiw6tuQ4NYV2ghKXACxNwPkRl?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?hs2zl0MBNyQ7tDTzK1kbNH9ZTqC/i1ScEPuyJZcsDKbi2iDg1qGbleQKXnF7?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?5Nxil2MNZKz/Ck9IpXDY8nmyuaR68GWKU70bEjR4b2KRbw9neLA/+qfJ/oAg?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?qDLtYJYWNKYb13kVF75SY/FBmInt4R0kn72ZhBQt+YX9sPT9Z8Jbbyx19ATA?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?jmFDRmUz7TVcuyK2YtO9ckIz33vjefhyaw2DV0FGIVKVXxC0BKKt58LNkVtr?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?DHo7z3hkNCipskELnz1evOyF9lEWxUYYL5NryXM7Z6HM9mZbk8VXIURNyorV?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Z4XaNW0gfDqMHBuvLGZKJh+op3J04haM3/Ix4yPDBngG1ZFkM/KWrd4dQHaM?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?zu4A+AXHyiAiQxUqAOwe/sc8UXZ/raa0Sxd2snXrK7wKcVPtA2VH7vIvTA+b?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?rkVbFNb6JuUCkQtZSXnRYtmpI+dppAip9a3wTjWBzVTL7y0d668lp4OrwRH3?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?A/0B0Z/s0Py8K1/t/Ee00WGTyDsxoY2VU/cTgoloSknkPhNc85Cv2aL47PhA?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?meC9qT/KKN8YmHxotah+tbrakQ6+5+HnqyKBQevAlIBZZqlfZH42WQZW7Ol8?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?5bo0Mw8VxE56UiT9C+Yts8LxtYqC7jSGvXzcgerbkLu25fWvzaiwdu8Vc0Y9?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?nkoTol406Sy6GVqhcuYOuqtXPFSZ/9Vhh8BBK7+1Cxm4F6XfKfV5amMDrZlV?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?u8xFYyfaViTRO/FtmpZBGseWHzEyxu3+NznfX5Mc4FKx99Pn/vCeNUTMOOmJ?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?RjwKNXUQfVs2gysH0V13oDRl92vCa2yGm85REqSFN3jURbV4CvyV+QSy3h6N?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?JT/aedZAt56NawuDOajTsrlhRXRKMCsKH/3/k2yImj/SfN2WYCQky60NvVgM?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Y++hWo7NeyVfK1g1Kdi859Mp?=
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SenderIP:209.85.215.46;WIMS-SPF:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-DKIM:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-822:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050)(102420017);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">Test body



--b1_158c240a0e56c955eb9db88446716a3c--
```

Inbox message source:

```
Received: from VI1PR0601MB2591.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.173.70.12) by
 VI1PR0601MB2591.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.173.70.12) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id
 15.1.619.10 via Mailbox Transport; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 10:39:42 +0000
Received: from HE1PR06CA0046.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.164.28.142) by
 VI1PR0601MB2591.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.173.70.12) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id
 15.1.619.10; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 10:39:42 +0000
Received: from HE1EUR01FT037.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:f400:7e1f::208) by HE1PR06CA0046.outlook.office365.com
 (2a01:111:e400:c45f::14) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_0,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id 15.1.619.10 via Frontend
 Transport; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 10:39:41 +0000
Received: from SNT004-MC1F2.hotmail.com (10.152.0.57) by
 HE1EUR01FT037.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.1.83) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.1.619.6 via Frontend Transport; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 10:39:40 +0000
Received: from mail-wm0-f52.google.com ([74.125.82.52]) by SNT004-MC1F2.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Sun, 11 Sep 2016 03:39:37 -0700
Received: by mail-wm0-f52.google.com with SMTP id b187so94890781wme.1
        for <alex.velickiy@hotmail.com>; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 03:39:37 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=GOfR8gNv8g23IYQjHpSeTocHbgB08Xn6c28qAl+Q43Q=;
        b=zkNwvp+2vLy6CoohyZJFgnt7Ecpue7sAkRGHwz7/trfeySLXKAxpo5hvWhfhGi7dHN
         ElcTcS52RfiWF1uXil1yp4mtcWBUaDW1qxO352emzdj/dSjpmCv2hA+RdSxqPLTr6OvO
         BegS0pvw8v7GthCO8ETFsdu2zB7y0uKnj153flnasRcGYo/Df+/1tCWHGv980A0+76vZ
         99LKJ4eTcuS85C+k+eHHWAyiRbFCnOOc/SejR32HEkFgPOXvRG/Oy0sGPtiKOi3+1Zug
         tGwywA2TCk8FsIxSnHcLZiJpYYMdvegpJtZf+Vpeo1dhZk5LQ66woZFJ76vyxFftyNiE
         7PNg==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=GOfR8gNv8g23IYQjHpSeTocHbgB08Xn6c28qAl+Q43Q=;
        b=jrbOi3ArQtFDAEI9fzDk1peZVhdcgf1y3yIyUbxrif+fjWv8Ya5n5xNTahDNRITJaM
         XuhRS+D1U7Ywy+LfNdXdyGyHVKrSKUfEeIB8ArIVYNtiFqOsKE6JgKT0LdqDlMiKn1Mq
         qdYLwXuqqyLjbGh+9YjWsDN3uH2nMJsQYqzPUogFSAKK+SPbuN0CWb5/NJLWk70nTW+j
         yCz4/3GIW5pp3RP1+47N3E5N+OM4cZswoIuoSeVdOcVZnHsEogjcBr9MHThQPKveE85p
         qC3Umtx69oNf8LQwbwVPgMmZrjCvsCnFis4FvfsA/awsR/fTFmo9Lb0qKEs22gyDCxXr
         ljDg==
X-Gm-Message-State: AE9vXwNb6wmclhgQ8neIxZS9eLbaHX/h7LSiErMMtGaYWLIu7LpO5NkgimMcr0nKQjHmAFPId7uD129sIgneAw==
X-Received: by 10.28.87.194 with SMTP id l185mr261658wmb.31.1473590376777;
 Sun, 11 Sep 2016 03:39:36 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.194.144.51 with HTTP; Sun, 11 Sep 2016 03:39:36 -0700 (PDT)
From: Alex Vel <avel80274@gmail.com>
Date: Sun, 11 Sep 2016 13:39:36 +0300
Message-ID: <CACdShAjf+aHx9Wd=w44hPUYmt-+=4xC7JJFvMcjaPNN3qGUuwg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Test subj
To: alex.velickiy@hotmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="001a1147dd18f3cb81053c38feda"
Return-Path: avel80274@gmail.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 11 Sep 2016 10:39:37.0648 (UTC) FILETIME=[CB491B00:01D20C18]
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: dd924932-a063-4592-25bc-08d3da2ff04a
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
CMM-sender-ip: 74.125.82.52
CMM-sending-ip: 74.125.82.52
CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 74.125.82.52;
 identity alignment result is pass and alignment mode is relaxed)
 smtp.mailfrom=avel80274@gmail.com; dkim=pass (identity alignment result is
 pass and alignment mode is relaxed) header.d=gmail.com; x-hmca=pass
 header.id=avel80274@gmail.com
CMM-X-SID-PRA: avel80274@gmail.com
CMM-X-AUTH-Result: PASS
CMM-X-SID-Result: PASS
CMM-X-Message-Status: n:n
CMM-X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0w
CMM-X-Message-Info: gamVN+8Ez8V+RHg+F+brAdJ7vH/meoUgJ2RGAqgdRAFOQkBtPg1BmxDRJPpS3YHrl4FCOrJGN8t02lEYCCKZIN0yw0lVUbULCTPUzkoj6pTC96XekUahC223Bp1zf3JXcmiOKwjCmix67meSoGk0Zm8bleQs7Ht3sXq0w1ix9ScZPHKSl0IWByuoQvjyKcaJ1n/NX8byp9EI1BobCJ0kJWzkTMfT0Fm5YfHbHp/lyrEFRz+4dagmEQ==
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;HE1EUR01FT037;1:PtpHAU+ubVRe6hw96IUAtOrG/4rEPo5DuCMQxvvVe5mLEjvUf/GMz1dnfyI2FUz1w676z+EUFigeEQuCdMgk1KoYa8LLIszkbDusrLgcF4jC9FtxNJXFFaX5W7u3qKWTdO88KNAw5hB+mQeiv/PZKg==
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;SFS:(98900003);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:1;SRVR:VI1PR0601MB2591;H:SNT004-MC1F2.hotmail.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:en;
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: dd924932-a063-4592-25bc-08d3da2ff04a
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VI1PR0601MB2591;2:dOJPMWgcHAQIrf6t3yxWlfwWCVjkmkO0HrSw7+HdSlYltC8wCGRE3gXTvO4DrTYcrm1/3XoFVmR8Rq5D4k1rCLHoFmkk1Oic47Tdlx+MvfyiErisjPfb/TU8pnItbbm0zFBtSD7UPKT/YCqmXOQPQe2j/apXB+ae+bUvogW5tQaTH8P6izR27KxkWlhgeE6GXoj2I6JURCpP4UzGxNj9Ng==;3:Z2ijRPaGmGm8LSDQGE9LkRq0WWZ+X7zJV5NYQUBXgsJ0B7+dh/bKuIJshcRwj0BGzgBiDUoG2QDqoV/fyAgatWJD5y97aq69q0QLoWEv2cNvrnQ7/pDisXo/ey/joer3NVV/Ju7WcP1dbo1B/DCAPiFvgVp9sGqpTxFDLomgMLE=;25:4giPhVWaxGw0+kC49F7V/UymX0N4xNKfMldYniEtEyae+bw0CUyvdrj+UV/QPsCEu48z6XMnt+lyuaFRk/wKqXJRuEPi9fmzuX6QTVcFvEb9XHpvpJ8SO/2ugZYFBxVokSQJvASkcbMdKVcrKY8zf2yLJoql4gl8pyXPZLjyumMqmSPG+z7z35xcoEfByzW31LrteES6FEIyRqEKa291aa/4yB55tYQBKvRS9D6Y6i3tTpoqIsxgnPAFkA2db6/SgcFSgg4+r/sVNhJQmWdZYU9jgg29OW2/0DpAL5E9aNcnq5XXLV4R0Ppw1CEKP0HcgBMGyGrO7KvMdjl2izabqA==;31:ATBRbrMQf8o2TRzSBcy3/hVX/UR+Ojx6jBbNkGk52mjc0vYzB+zwot0aTcC+tvqndzAigrhklocnmI06DpsuMHlYzlBfN8paddOiOVwUo5VX9Fm7O5P+tuyw0gHzkSSa
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(8291501002);SRVR:VI1PR0601MB2591;
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(82015046);SRVR:VI1PR0601MB2591;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:VI1PR0601MB2591;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VI1PR0601MB2591;4:pthrsxadQYACPFUgPqVge/RZdZR0dCpn63Q6yU23NdBjUnkGSmJTEusCkc2bG2pLJ4KBpmo+NBS8PrDcHvEalUI68O7OglZj+VPwjCny3WAVO1oaPPLeQBkHu71HG02BhTRXZVVNgUI3UbQ2L9O6lDpumqVBM//LZg0u29eMpE0=;23:KswOJOnR7rQSKQxn50HIW6GYjW7Oc4eWEajY345IuI6JZwGI6BG8tHOvfDb5s38JlDZe0zXRAKM19Qak1cUFmnhPw5RY1f4Vn/dsJBkUxncBZdgwQeipFF1cfEThZrymt7F2l5iQ83CF1onyaFOOZaupAz3OqX/dhPVeZnrbk2RaCsNyc2+5IOy0urIvLM/O;6:qxoWfO68HyatmRBB39DxJxQ8dn+Kd+tov6NbwgRoIJx7/rb5siJQ/AVMLYG0MaRgfMzcb9PMNRZeqmZ18TVF+BmL/I5HC0u1t+tb4XeSwiTo1HBaq2qUc1o1By3LNVaq4UiDGdGshuGxlRr2lBd6xgT1wsm0o3sfqAVTzcrb2bKgT02m/16uuGxcwynwbDulbrXV319R2STgQ6VMOewCFw==;5:1wXjHwYDFir8qJEuWNXfDlsQIAKRkaVcY001uaHDLQ6wcalaXpC2NOvTpxVS67uXEE8n3KJLxpu0wpRGmF+pswwGKUUDf7FHE9SM6F+Me+1lj3DuqxOp9JvDdLFJ7H4IUHhZmVjLTsltbBTpnckrfQ==;24:k7S4pg50c2LYXQMW0l0omb1SWrobcHTZNI2azk5pTufaJsvtgZiNBoDtiPSGd6mHQi3ol59+sds1NnxhNFqXZiYiuWIzN4h/y4Y/ZIHYi94=
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 1
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:99
SpamDiagnosticMetadata: NSPM
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VI1PR0601MB2591;7:OXjbuNzrRFkxVQX1zLedl/kYW7CzF7Ey1IdmxXl2thq5tllvFtJjq9i9IGl/6sjQLvU/lQr4AvX9zzzl3xX9m3MshXiZ8rRSNYvVWxCYSOotjbHmTO8KmhSAEovltjIP1a+IkGscat15zn0sb9qveB9ao7JDCknHy/QX37/XlpD9rNbtjurZ2Fptbz/kJWG9R36DVEezpWSOiGsoChTisQAu+95eXyTkPHfXWQfrmnFknSlR4UuUXmomp6+AAfw1aYkBjFvhuuu1vtyQZf1cHA==
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 11 Sep 2016 10:39:40.5956
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: VI1PR0601MB2591
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: HE1EUR01FT037.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.8252966
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;VI1PR0601MB2591;9: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
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;WIMS-SenderIP:74.125.82.52;WIMS-SPF:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-DKIM:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-822:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050);
MIME-Version: 1.0

--001a1147dd18f3cb81053c38feda
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;VI1PR0601MB2591;9: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
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;WIMS-SenderIP:74.125.82.52;WIMS-SPF:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-DKIM:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-822:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050);

Test body

--001a1147dd18f3cb81053c38feda
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;VI1PR0601MB2591;9:f9o+j523A3Y51rLbDamjIiUIjglgTkpGnO3s/Oj+eiLC90A9dvuMWGMeN01QsdblPOLGDXYnvgKgU+QYjqGFaBCziV4msMlz9oSSObT0TICX6r8d5innFxvM5QASMQxt6xVJNENxDg52iXfNeVlkdiUJg2ib02aWj0JtUjlYW3u1jgJH+35APJz9XxDXhl69YWB0u3Y1zxPTdW544V3yVTkZpRwD1a5Ut78JnM1/MCo5ZVBr6Hba60s3kY5lG5K7hFiyuYYUd075puTAo/5TKqtBHl2mAk808bKqrxhI0H2lWrWNyFybuvWhhsOIV+yMgU3U/sTuKp6SCMEB9CA/VEy1rIOzt2SVUsvv3RhC7lj9Rw3+ZjuaFlICN3No7EUk6alCimEUTSw5dY+/Vw6hdqPvgrByvVkCadVrjcUrQCJlHipCzTN7iHfHGreMxvp21RXe3Us5kGKSWddf/lMYGVbt+zxrm8nApTquVHEPUwie6ezKJ7gcK0aOM0u1FcaOhkHPbymBYZ5zwW6NFNEIsZhilGODgtoWlrMdQpkPRxVbdL9VR5/zJpyYM6sakxMLgj8Z8FgQjCGDDfckIaDZKH8P0nQMymwDfiCbwBXKQfx6QfDXNQwkPRcQBBqNlCvb8eK0EDuuKSDTiUs4B4m1STR78YXw2+mN/rRFMXPkaS5E2tJ+pA0g3Dxh2OSX+TsbausDam+a1ys1+KVaFEjaQCmdeuLQC1WdgswUSaKgsvUuHvApYHgMVUi98CFxFDi7mWrP8zLuwO9cnfoAm26cRz186Y2RtFB5hBJhEOxuy8BAB7OZYJHhC2D5ahH00jmg6raoiedYNQFis4SMtpwiWg==
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;WIMS-SenderIP:74.125.82.52;WIMS-SPF:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-DKIM:gmail%2ecom;WIMS-822:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:avel80274%40gmail%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050);

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><div dir="ltr">Test body<br></div>

--001a1147dd18f3cb81053c38feda--
```

Comment: You seem to be doing everything right, and all the headers look positive, but unfortunately you have absolutely no control over what gmail or hotmail considers to be spam. You could try opening a ticket with Hotmail support - I've had good outcomes from that in the past.

Comment: try send your emails to service like https://www.mail-tester.com/
I beleive it can be still an issue with that gmail own app is correctly designated as sender but your php app and server probably not. Can also be something relevant to DMARC mechanic and policy from Hotmail.

Comment: Any luck getting this issue resolved?

Comment: @johnny Well, it's been a long time since I tried to solve it. As far as I remember I integrated with some mailing service. But also as far as I remember, it didn't solve problem completely - some email messages were still missing.